Vertex AI on AWS EC2- Unable to reach Vertex AI from .NET 8 app. Works fine with .NET 4.8 app
I am trying to reach vertex ai using Google.Cloud.AIPlatform.V1 for a Predict response but I am getting the following error:

Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Unavailable", Detail="Error connecting to subchannel.", DebugException="System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.")
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10060): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|285_0(AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs saea, ValueTask connectTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Grpc.Net.Client.Balancer.Internal.SocketConnectivitySubchannelTransport.TryConnectAsync(ConnectContext context)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Grpc.Net.Client.Balancer.Internal.ConnectionManager.PickAsync(PickContext context, Boolean waitForReady, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Grpc.Net.Client.Balancer.Internal.BalancerHttpHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall2.RunCall(HttpRequestMessage request, Nullable1 timeout)
at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCallRetryExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_0`2.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---

However when the same code is used as part of a .NET 4.8 console app, I am able to receive the Prediction response.
I have tried setting http_proxy and grpc_proxy. This issue only occurs in AWS EC2 environment and not in any of the local or private virtual machines that we have.
Looking for suggestions. Thanks.
PredictionServiceClientBuilder ClientBuilder = new PredictionServiceClientBuilder();
ClientBuilder.JsonCredentials = File.ReadAllText(credentialsPath);
ClientBuilder.Endpoint = "us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com";

var _predictionServiceClient = ClientBuilder.Build();

Console.WriteLine("Asking Google Vertex - How are you");
var prompt = "How are you ?";
var endpoint = EndpointName.FromProjectLocationPublisherModel("xxxx-xxxx-xxxx", "us-central1", "google", "text-bison@001").ToString();
var content = prompt;
var instanceValue = new wkt::Value
{
    StructValue = new wkt::Struct
    {
        Fields =
    {
        {
            "content", new wkt::Value
            {
                StringValue = content
            }
        }
    }
    }
};

var instances = new List<wkt::Value>
{
    instanceValue
};

var parameters = new wkt::Value
{
    StructValue = new wkt::Struct
    {
        Fields =
    {
        { "temperature", new wkt::Value { NumberValue = 0.5} },
        { "maxOutputTokens", new wkt::Value { NumberValue = 1000 } },
        { "topP", new wkt::Value { NumberValue = 0.45 } },
        { "topK", new wkt::Value { NumberValue = 10 } }
    }
    }
};

var response = await _predictionServiceClient.PredictAsync(endpoint, instances, parameters);
Console.WriteLine();

Console.WriteLine("Response - ");
Console.WriteLine(response.Predictions[0].StructValue.Fields["content"].StringValue);


Double check firewall rules. If ports are allowed, try "ping" command see what does it return
